# Why does my dog want me to, basically, massage her jaw?

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, psychology, chewing

My dog has been very weird lately. She used to lick my hands when she was a puppy, but doesn't do it anymore. This past week or so, she does it all the time! She also never had gas, but this past week or so it's every time she sleeps. She is not a big dog, so she sleeps a lot. The weirdest thing is that she is always, *always*, wanting to be petted.

She has always been a bit needy when it came to massages, but now it's crazy! She wants her jaw kind of massaged and rubbed on. She likes the chest, too.

We have this thing where if I pat her side and said "okay" it means I'm done. She usually understands this. But now she will shove her nose in my hand to get me to keep going.

I wonder if it's because she is a little old. She is about 8 years old, but she is expected to live up to 16. Her teeth are messed up pretty badly. She is missing the front ones and the back ones are gross looking. Maybe they hurt or something like that, I don't know.

I'm scared that something may be up with her.

Could you please help me and tell me what possible reasons there might be for her recent changes in behaviour?

Comment: Have you given her different food lately? Could be the reason for her gas. Has she been eating normally or less than usual? If she eats less, her teeth could be the cause.

Answer (score 8):

If your dog's teeth are "gross looking", then it's likely there's a build-up of plaque and maybe tooth-ache.

I'd really suggest taking her to the vet and getting her teeth looked at and get some general advice in what teeth care you can provide her.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Snow's (user8045's) reply, please get the dog to a vet if the teeth are bad!

As for other possibilities, it could be that you did it to them once and they enjoyed it, so keeps going back for more. I have a dog that loves to bury his head in between your legs or the sofa, or paw the side of his cheek to get you to pet them. I also have a cat that will headbutt your hands (or feet) to get you to pet him on the face.

I would liken it to a pleasurable experience, much like why we humans pay to have head massages.